# How can i store the selected tab on a RadTabStrip that can be returned to on back button click

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, telerik

I currently use a hidden input field that is assigned the value of the tab that has just been selected, via javascript, like so:

```
function onTabSelecting(sender, args) {
    var tab = args.get_tab(); //get selected tab
    document.getElementById("MainContent_hdnPreviousTab").value = tab.get_text(); //assign value to hidden field
    if (tab.get_pageViewID()) { //ignore
    tab.set_postBack(false);
    }
}
```

I then use this assigned value when the page is returned to, on client-side (ajax) PageLoad() event:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var runOnce = false;
    function pageLoad() {
        if (!runOnce) {
            var lastTab = document.getElementById("<%= hdnPreviousTab.ClientID %>");
            if (lastTab.value) {
                if (tabStrip) {
                    var tab = tabStrip.findTabByText(lastTab.value);
                    if (tab) {
                        tab.click();
                    }
                }
            }
            runOnce = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Currently in IE this works fine (I know right?), the value that was previously set in javascript is still there and i am able to lcoate the tab that the user left the page on. However in FF, Chrome, etc. i have no such luck. The hidden field is returned to it's empty state (value = "") regardless of utilising viewstate or not.

Very curious as to whether anyone has an alternative method that would be appropriate in this situation. Please let me know if this is unclear.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use localstorage.

`localStorage.setItem('tab', value);`

Comment: Thanks man, that is in fact how i'd just decided to do it in the end.